# How perform transformation based on a condition?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe and I want perform a transformation based on the datatype of the column.

Based on the datatype of the column I want to convert it to JSON string.

I tried using when otherwise, it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I'm trying to do,

```
>>> dtype = df.dtypes[0][1]
>>> dtype
'string'
>>> df.withColumn('json_col', when(dtype=='string', 'value').otherwise(to_json('value')))
```

I get the below error with this statement

**TypeError: condition should be a Column**

Any help would be appretiated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if` in this case.

```
df2 = df.withColumn('json_col', col('value') if dtype=='string' else to_json('value'))
```